# JS Code convert to Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to convert the following code into TypeScript. It is an array with objects. and then I want to use it inside a class. I tried to use an interface but I could not proceed much.  Please help me.

```
var accountModel = {
        name: 'ABC Account',
        accounts: [
            { balance: 10000, description: 'Checking' },
            { balance: 50000, description: 'Savings' }
        ]
    };
```

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, you do not need to make any changes for this to be valid typescript

Comment: Are you asking what's the TypeScript way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want type checking on your account model data, you can use type aliases

```
type AccountModel = {name:string, accounts:Array<Account>}
type Account = {balance:number, description:string}
```

Now your IDE will check if your variable has the correct content:

```
let acc : AccountModel = {
        name: 'ABC Account',
        accounts: [
            { balance: 10000, description: 'Checking' },
            { balance: 50000, description: 'Savings' }
        ],
        test: 'hello' // The IDE will complain: 'test' is
                      // not assignable to accountModel
 };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How we can call it with a class object?

Comment: there are some errors in your sent code 

I run on http://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: I even created a version with classes and interfaces [in this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbm75v0z/7/) :) I think this is better!

Comment: thank you. how I can convert the following directive into TS. 

App.directive('emp', [function ($scope) {
            return function (scope,element,attrs) {
                if (scope.name === "ABC")
                    element.css({color:'red'});
            };
        }]);

Comment: I think that's a different question :) But it should already work in typescript, even if you don't define the types explicitly. Also, defining the types for nested anonymous functions can become a bit unreadable, I'd prefer rewriting the code in a more OOP way to avoid this.